# How to check if file exist that start with string

Tags: node.js

So I have this file "FILE 001", no extension, the number change, and I need to see if such a file exist, for example "FILE .*" would work.

How do I do this in node?  Here is what I have:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const FilePath: string = "C:/API_TEMP/FILE 001";
if (fs.existsSync(FilePath)) {
    console.log("File Already Exist");
}
```

Comment: you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob

Comment: You can list the contents of the directory and check if any entry starts with `File `.

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna try getting **all** files in `C:/API_TEMP/`, iterating over them and check whether the filename starts with `FILE`.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const files = fs.readdirSync('C:/API_TEMP/')

for (let file of files) {
 if (file.startsWith('FILE')) {
  console.log('File already exists')
  continue
 }
}
```

Alternatively, there are some packages such as:

- [find](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find)
- [fast-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob)